# Using FTP.exe and mget to download files and directories from an FTP directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp

I am trying to set up an automatic download of the files from a FTP directory on a scheduled basis. The solution I have come up with is to create a batch file that will be ran by windows task scheduler. The batch file is as follows (so far)

```
prompt
open ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx
myuser
mypassword
lcd C:\localdir
cd /remotedir/
mget *
quit
```

The problem is that this does not get everything in the specified directory. Only the loose files in the directory such as a `.zip` or `.txt` file. I have searched the questions here to no avail. So how can I get `mget` to not only download loose files in the root directory but also download the sub-directories and containing files (keeping the structure intact)?

Comment: FTP.EXE in Windows doesn't have support for downloading folder trees.

Comment: Can you zip up the folder tree on the FTP server, ftp that file and then unzip it?  The file itself can be a self extracting zip file.  Add @foxidrive to your comment if you want me to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering this in case anyone else has a similar issue. The `ftp.exe` was a bust but I found out it is fairly easy using WinSCP just create a scheduled task in task scheduler and use the options section for command line parameters

Instructions for creating download script with WinSCP:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

Instructions for scheduling WinSCP transfer task:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule

WinSCP downloads directories recursively by default.